# How to pass the signing of a series of API function at address?

Tags: c#, api, http, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have such a signature in API:

`public IHttpActionResult PostUser_Hotel(float user ,float[] rating)`

How should I proceed address bar?

http://localhost://User_Hotel?user=1&rating

Comment: What kind of project is this? What infrastructure do you have to route HTTP requests to your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change signature a little to this one:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostUser_Hotel(float user, [FromUri]float[] rating)
```

And use address bar like this:
http://localhost://User_Hotel?user=1&rating=1&rating=2

Comment: Thank-You! it works!